# How do I setup temporary account lockout in Apache Syncope?

Tags: passwords, identity-management, apache-syncope

How do I setup Apache Syncope so that a user's account is automatically unlocked after X minutes since their last failed login attempt?  Where X is configurable.

I've already set the Global Account Policy's Maximum number of subsequent failed logins value.

I see that the user details in Syncope have a "Subsequent Failed Logins" field, but I don't see any field for Last Failed Login Date.  Do I have to setup a custom task for this somehow?

Answer (score -1):

This same question was answered on Apache Syncope user@ ML; check [1] for details.

Shortly, temporary account lockout is not supported.
By setting the "Global Account Policy's Maximum number of subsequent 
failed logins" you are in fact defining a *permanent* account lockout.

Anyway, an improvement in this area is possible.

[1] http://markmail.org/message/5ynjf6awr6uiroc4